# Как сделать редактируемую таблицу (CRUD) c редактируемыми полями (в т.ч. списки) и вычислениями?

Tags: javascript, html, css, table

Нужна помощь! Суть вопроса в том, что нужна таблица, где в колонках "Фамилия..." и "Марка...", можно было выбрать в выпадающем списке. В других колонка, ручной ввод. В идеале, в последней колонке подсчитывался пробег, после ввода начального и конечного километража.
[image: Наглядный пример]

```css
table {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;/* сделает ширину таблицы равной ширине блока контейнера, в котором она находится */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;/* границы ячеек первого ряда таблицы */
    empty-cells: show;
    
}
th {
    border: 2px solid black;/* границы ячеек тела таблицы */
    background-color: rgb(160, 221, 222);
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: rgb(176, 222, 161);
}

table {/* задаст фиксированную ширину для таблицы */
   width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    
    <title>КПП</title>
</head>
        <h1>Журнал КПП</h1>
        <div id="current_date_time_block"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                /* функция добавления ведущих нулей */
                /* (если число меньше десяти, перед числом добавляем ноль) */
                function zero_first_format(value)
                {
                    if (value < 10)
                    {
                        value='0'+value;
                    }
                    return value;
                }
                /* функция получения текущей даты и времени */
                function date_time()
                {
                    var current_datetime = new Date();
                    var day = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getDate());
                    var month = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getMonth()+1);
                    var year = current_datetime.getFullYear();
                    var hours = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getHours());
                    var minutes = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getMinutes());
                    var seconds = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getSeconds());

                    return day+"."+month+"."+year+" "+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
                }
                /* выводим текущую дату и время на сайт в блок с id "current_date_time_block" */
                setInterval(function () {
                     document.getElementById('current_date_time_block2').innerHTML = date_time();           
                 }, 1000); 
            </script>
        <div id="current_date_time_block2"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                                
            /* каждую секунду получаем текущую дату и время */
            /* и вставляем значение в блок с id "current_date_time_block2" */
                setInterval(function () {
                    document.getElementById('current_date_time_block2').innerHTML = date_time();           
                }, 1000);           
            </script> 
            
                                      
<body>
    <table class="table">
        <tr> <!--ряд с ячейками заголовков-->
            <th>№ п/п</th>
            <th>Фамилия водителя</th>
            <th>Марка/Модель машины</th>
            <th>№ путевого листа</th>
            <th>Начальный километраж</th>
            <th>Конечный километраж</th>
            <th>Пройдено км</th>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
            <td>данные</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!--Нумерация п/п-->
    <script>
        $('.table tr').each(function(i) {
        i && $(this).find('td:first').text(i);});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а вопрос в чем?

Comment: @DaniilLoban - Как сделать что бы в колонках "Фамилия..." и "Марка...", можно было выбрать в выпадающем списке. В других колонках, ручной ввод. В идеале, в последней колонке подсчитывался пробег, после ввода начального и конечного километража.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Реализация CRUD***

*без **D** - удаления

```js
const tableHeader = document.getElementById('tableHeader');
const tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody');
const NO_DATA = "нет данных";

// блок данных
const jurnalRows = [
  [1, 'Иванов', 'Волга', '1076-B2', 0, 10, 10]
]
const lastNames =[
  NO_DATA,
  "Иванов",
  "Петров",
  "Cидоров"
];
const models =[
   NO_DATA,
   "Жигули",
   "Волга",
   "Лада"
];
const columns = [ 
    {name: "№ п/п", source:null, className:"number"},
    {name: "Фамилия водителя", source:createSelect(lastNames), dataSource: lastNames, className: "lastName"},
    {name: "Марка/Модель машины", source:createSelect(models), dataSource: models, className: "model"},
    {name: "№ путевого листа", source:createInput('text'), dataSource: "", className:"listNumber"},
    {name: "Начальный километраж", source:createInput('number'), dataSource: 0, className: "begin"},
    {name: "Конечный километраж", source:createInput('number'), dataSource: 0,  className: "end"},
    {name: "Пройдено км", source:null, className: "sum"}        
]
// конец блока данных

// блок переменных
let currentRow = -1;
let currentCol = -1;
let currentCell = null;
const indexOfSum = columns.indexOf(columns.find( e => e.className === "sum"));
const indexOfBegin = columns.indexOf(columns.find( e => e.className === "begin"));
const indexOfEnd = columns.indexOf(columns.find( e => e.className === "end"));
// конец блока переменных

// подсчет колонки "Пройдено км"    
function calulate(event) {
  const cell = event.target;
  if (cell.parentNode.className === "begin") {
    jurnalRows[currentRow][indexOfSum] = jurnalRows[currentRow][indexOfEnd] - cell.value;
  } else if (cell.parentNode.className === "end") {
    jurnalRows[currentRow][indexOfSum] = cell.value - jurnalRows[currentRow][indexOfBegin];
  } 
  tableBody.children[currentRow].children[indexOfSum].textContent = jurnalRows[currentRow][indexOfSum]
}

function createInput(type) {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('type', type);
  input.addEventListener('change', calulate, false);
  return input;
}

function createSelect(list) {
    const select = document.createElement('select');
    select.cla
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value=i;
        option.textContent=list[i];
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
    return select;
}

const createCell = (text, className) => {
  const cell = document.createElement('td'); 
  cell.textContent=text
  if(className) cell.className = className;
  return cell;
}

const createHeader = () => {
  const row = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (i = 0; i< columns.length; i++){
   const cell = createCell(columns[i].name, columns[i].className);
   row.appendChild(cell);
  }
  return row;
}

const createRow = (rowData) => {
  const row = document.createElement('tr'); 
  for (i = 0; i< columns.length; i++){
   const cell= createCell(rowData[i], columns[i].className);
   row.appendChild(cell);
  }
  return row
}

function addNewRow() {
    const rowData = [jurnalRows.length +1, ...Array(columns.length-1).fill(NO_DATA)];
    jurnalRows.push(rowData)
    tableBody.appendChild(createRow(rowData))
}

function addRow(rowData) {
  tableBody.appendChild(createRow(rowData))
}

const fillTable = () => {
  tableHeader.appendChild(createHeader())
  for (let i = 0; i < jurnalRows.length; i++){
    addRow(jurnalRows[i])
  }
  //addNewRow()
}

fillTable()

const showEditField = () => {
  if (event.target.tagName !== 'TD') return;
  const cell = event.target;
  const column = columns.find(e => e.className === cell.className);
  const index = columns.indexOf(column);
  // запоминаем последний выбор в данных
  if (currentCell && currentCol !== -1 && currentRow !== -1){
    if (Array.isArray(columns[currentCol].dataSource)){
      jurnalRows[currentRow][currentCol] = columns[currentCol].dataSource[+columns[currentCol].source.value];
      currentCell.textContent = jurnalRows[currentRow][currentCol];                 
    } else {
      jurnalRows[currentRow][currentCol] = columns[currentCol].source.value;
      currentCell.textContent = jurnalRows[currentRow][currentCol];                 
    }
  }
  // переносим ячейку выбора
  if (column.source) {
    oldData = cell.innerHTML;
    cell.innerHTML = "";
    if (Array.isArray(column.dataSource)){
      column.source.value = `${column.dataSource.indexOf(oldData)}`;
    } else {
      column.source.value = oldData !== NO_DATA ? oldData : column.dataSource;
    }
    cell.appendChild(column.source)
    currentCol = index;
    currentRow = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(tableBody.children, cell.parentNode);
    currentCell = cell;
    // console.table(jurnalRows);
  }       
}
tableBody.addEventListener('click',showEditField, false)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">-->
  <style type="text/css">
    table {
      /*position: absolute; убрано для примера*/
      width: 100px;/* сделает ширину таблицы равной ширине блока контейнера, в котором она находится */
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: 1px solid black;/* границы ячеек первого ряда таблицы */
      empty-cells: show;
    }
    th {
      border: 2px solid black;/* границы ячеек тела таблицы */
      background-color: rgb(160, 221, 222);
    }
    td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: rgb(176, 222, 161);
    }
    table {/* задаст фиксированную ширину для таблицы */
     width: 900px;
    }
    select {
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px;
      font-size: 10px;
    }        
    input {
      width: 90%;
      height: 20px;
      font-size: 10px;
    } 
  </style>
  <title>КПП</title>
</head>
  <h1>Журнал КПП</h1>
  <div id="current_date_time_block"></div>
  <div id="current_date_time_block2"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      /* функция добавления ведущих нулей */
      /* (если число меньше десяти, перед числом добавляем ноль) */
      function zero_first_format(value) {
          return (value < 10) ? value='0'+value : value;
      }
      /* функция получения текущей даты и времени */
      function date_time(){
          const current_datetime = new Date();
          const day = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getDate());
          const month = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getMonth()+1);
          const year = current_datetime.getFullYear();
          const hours = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getHours());
          const minutes = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getMinutes());
          const seconds = zero_first_format(current_datetime.getSeconds());
          return `${day}.${month}.${year} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
      }
      /* выводим текущую дату и время на сайт в блок с id "current_date_time_block" */
      setInterval(function () {
           document.getElementById('current_date_time_block2').innerHTML = date_time();           
       }, 1000); 
    </script> 
<body>
  <table class="table">
    <thead id="tableHeader"><!--ряд с ячейками заголовков-->
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBody"></tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="button" onclick="addNewRow()">Добавить строку</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Пример использования:

1. выносим добавленные стили  в файл `css/style.css`
2. два скрипта (`для времни` и `для таблицы`) выносим в файл `js/index.js` и подлючаем:

так перед закрытием тега `</body>`

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

либо там же где и стили с аттрибутом `defer`

```
<script defer src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: я извиняюсь, но как подключить скрипт? Я уже не знаю что пробовать. Тут запускается, а в браузере таблицы просто нет. Ещё раз извиняюсь за свою тупость.

Comment: все нормально, что именно не получается? могу отслать одним файлом если нужно

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Всё работает. Вы лучший! Просто человечище!
Буду допиливать дальше, если получится)

Comment: Приятно, удачи!

Comment: подскажите, с вами можно связаться как-то?